# Float div with fixed width right to div of unknown width

Tags: html, css

I want to float an div with fixed width on the right of a div with an unknown width if there is enough space left. My code is:

```css
#wrapper {
  float: left;
}
#description {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#preview {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 483px;
  width: 239.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="description">
    <div id="paragraph1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="paragraph2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="paragraph3">
      Lorem ipsum
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>DLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>ILorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="preview">
    <img src="screen.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

It want the div preview to float to left the the text of description. It is important that I use the div and not just the plain img tag.

Comment: do you want the preview div to be inside description div???

Comment: no next to it on the right

Comment: ok..but,the default width of a div will be always 100%;

Comment: Ah ok that was the point I missed: Can I use something for the width of the description div like: 100%-previewDivWidth

Comment: you know the preview div's width,right??so, i think you convert that to % and then give the width of the description div in %.try it..may be that'll work..

Comment: This won't work because the preview div needs to have a fixed width. If I give it a % it will be resized based on the parent div which is 100% and then it will have a variable width which I don't want

Comment: IS this what your needing? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poqfrqnp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/w2aom5a5/1/

The issue was that you were floating the other div:

```
#wrapper {
    float:left;
}
#description {

}
#preview {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    height: 483px;
    width: 239.5px;
}
```

Once you remove the float on #description and move the image container to the top, it'll start working. I also changed #preview to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't put a size to #description :

Put `#preview` before `#description` in you html and remove his `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for this. This way you do not have to change the order of divs:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#description {
  display: table-cell;
}
#preview {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 239.5px;
  height: 483px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="description">
    <!-- dummy content -->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div id="preview">
    <!-- dummy image -->
  </div>
</div>
```